# Find Matching Word, or Number, in a Column and return corresponding rows

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm not sure how well I'm going to articulate this, but hopefully, it makes sense.

I have a Google Sheet that houses 3 tabs, 2 of which hold data while the 3rd is an overview of the 2. I'm trying to create a small search formula to easily find specific data from 1 of the 2 sheets.

Here is how one sheet looks:

```
       A               B        C            D
   1| Name     |    Number  | Type       | Role
   --------------------------------------------
   2| John Doe | 012345     | Tech       | MKT 
   3| Jane Doe | 012445     | Business   | DEV 
   4| Jane Doe | 012445     | Business   | MKT 
   5| Arthur   | 015475     | Home       | SALE 
   6| Arthur   | 011111     | Tech       | MKT
```

And there are about 250 rows.

What I'm trying to do is see if a specific column matches the search term added to the primary sheet. 
E.g: "Arthur" in Column 1 ("Arthur" A2:A5). And, if it exists, return the data from each column in the corresponding row.

E.g: Data returned would be:

```
    A5 (Arthur), B5 (015475), C5 (Home), D5 (Sale)
```

Currently, I'm using the following formula in the main sheet which searches column A in Sheet 2 (A1 is the cell where I'm typing the name, e.g: Arthur) and outputs the first row:

```
    =Vlookup(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$K$200,1,False)
```

If there is a Match, the contents of that Cell is output. In this case, Arthur.

So, is there any way of extending this to also get the contents of all Cells in the matching Row?

But, I need to ensure it's going to be compatible in the event that this file is opened in MS Excel.

Thanks

EDIT: I've managed to solve my own problem:

```
   =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$K$20,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$A$1:$K$20=A2,ROW($A$1:$K$20)-ROW($C$1)+1),ROWS(A$1:K1))),"False")
```

However, this does not work for Duplicates.
Let's so, there are 2 Arthurs, this will only return the corresponding row for the last instance of Arthur it finds. Is there a way to have it return all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the below formula & the image. Hope the formula will solve your issue.If still, the problem exists please share a Sample sheet with some Sample data. I will try to resolve your issue.

Formula - `=QUERY(A3:D8,"Select A,B,C,D where A = '"&F2&"'",0)`

Image for reference - [image]

If you want to include the headers please replace 0 with 1.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is the filter function. Please try:

`=filter('Sheet1'!A:D, A:A = "Arthur")`

Or a query function.

**NOTE!** `query` and `filter` are not compatible with [excel](/questions/tagged/excel).

For excel you may adopt [this formula](http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=119:vlookup-multiple-values-return-multiple-corresponding-values-for-one-lookup-value&catid=77&Itemid=473) for your needs:

`=INDEX('Sheet1'!B$1:B$500, SMALL(IF("Arthur"='Sheet1'!$A$1:$A$500, ROW('Sheet1'!$A$1:$A$500)-ROW('Sheet1'!$A$1)+1), ROW('Sheet1'!1:1)))`

Drag it down and right to adjust the result.